# Show that for a set $A$, $|^A 2|$ = $|^{|A| }2|$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

**Question:** Show that for a set $A$, $|^A 2|$ = $|^{|A| }2|$.

**Comments:** This is a part of a larger problem that I'm attempting to solve and it seems like the equality is true, but I'm not quite sure how to prove it. Idea: I need to find a bijection from $|^{|A| }2|$ to $|^A 2|$ and I can use that there is a bijection from $|A|$ to $A$, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Any input appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain the notation?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes, $^A B$ means the set of all functions from A to B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function $A\to 2$ is a function which, for each element of $A$, decides whether it goes in bin $1$ or in bin $2$. Or whether it is selected or dropped. Therefore it is a way to formalize any subset of $A$, and therefore an element of the power set of $A$. The set of all such functions is therefore the powerset of $A$, often denoted as $2^A$.

A function $A\to\lvert A\rvert$ maps a set to its cardinality. That cardinality is a cardinal number, and as such is considered to be a set of ordinal numbers. The cardinality of $A$ is the cardinality of $\lvert A\rvert$ itself.

For the cardinality of a powerset, it does not matter what the underlying set is. Only its cardinality is important. To illustrate this, consider the task of choosing items from a bag containing $10$ distinct items. There are $2^{10}$ ways to choose items, since each single item may be chosen or not chosen. It does not matter at all *what* items you are choosing from, be it apples, nuts or whatever.

To formalize things, you'll need three steps:

$$
\bigl\lvert A\to 2\bigr\rvert
\quad\leftrightarrow\quad
A\to 2
\quad\leftrightarrow\quad
\lvert A\rvert\to 2
\quad\leftrightarrow\quad
\bigl\lvert\lvert A\rvert\to 2\bigr\rvert
$$

The outermost bijections are simply due to the fact that a cardinal number has as many elements as the cardinality it signifies. The inner bijection does the same on the arguments of the domain of the function.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** If $f\colon A\to|A|$ is a bijection, and $g\colon |A|\to 2$, consider $g\circ f$.

Comment: So is tbe $g\circ f$ the bijection then? We say that if $f(a)=0$, then $g\circ f = 0$ and if $f(a)=1$, then $g\circ f$=1.

Comment: @Sid, no, it's not a bijection. This is why I wrote "hint" at the beginning. What **is** $g\circ f$?

Comment: It is the composite function $g(f(a))$ for all $a$ in $A$.

Comment: Think, what are the relevant sets to your problem?

Comment: The set of all functions from the cardinality of A to a set with the cardinality of 2 and the set of all functions from A to a set with the cardinality of 2? Which we want to show that have the same cardinality? I am apparently a little lost.

Comment: Sid, and to which of them do $g$ and $g\circ f$ belong to?

Comment: I think the latter, since it is g(f(a)) but not f(g(a)). How does this help us find a proof (the right bijection)?

Comment: Good. So you started with $g$, which belongs to the former and by composing $f$ you ended with a function in the latter. Does that hint you of a possible bijection?

Comment: I appreciate your time in trying to make me understand this, I am thinking hard about it but I'm not sure. We have a function that belongs to the set which we want to find a bijection into, and we have another function that belongs to the set from which we want to find a bijection. We want it to be the other way, right? So would f(g(a)) suffice (instead of g(f(a))) or am I thinking about this incorrectly?

Comment: We have $g$ in $^{|A|}2$ and $g\circ f\in{}^A2$. What was the mechanism that took us from one set to the other?

Comment: The mechanism was a function composition. Do we need to do that again, so that we get g(g(f))? That we we go from $^{|A|}2$ to $^A 2$.

Comment: You need to define a function between sets of functions. This means that you need to define a function $F$ which takes $g\in{}^{|A|}2$ and returns some $F(g)\in{}^A2$.

Comment: I am trying, but how can we do so and be sure it is a bijection?

Comment: Well, if you choose $F$ right, then you should be able to show that it is a bijection. Begin by showing that $g\neq g'$ implies $F(g)\neq F(g')$, and then show that if $h\in{}^A2$ then there is some $g$ such that $F(g)=h$.

Comment: I don't know. I suppose we have to use $f$ since we know it is a bijection, but it uses elements the wrong set, we want to have it the other way around. Is there any way you can give me a stronger hint (I'm not good at this) or show me what bijection you had in mind?

Comment: @Sid: Okay, here's a stronger hint. I already gave you the definition $F$ using $f$.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you right ... $f$ is the bijection we were looking for? By the way, if you are tired of talking about this, I understand.

Comment: @Sid, no $f$ is a bijection from $A$ to $|A|$. We want to take a function in $^{|A|}2$ and end up with a function in $^A2$. What method, which appears in the comments does that and uses $f$?

Comment: I don't know, I give up.

Comment: Sleep on it. I am willing to help you, but I won't tell you the answer.